# Optimization of HTML-Styling (Limitation of p-Tags)

Tags: html, css, tags, signature

How can I ensure that I don't have to use p tags for HTML styling? Currently, I am using `<p style="xyz">ExampleName</p>`, but it seems to be disrupting the entire layout. How can I optimize this, preferably without or with minimal use of CSS?

With the usage of p-tags my whole signature creates paragraphs that I don't want.
I pretty much want the same outcome as if I would use the p-Tags.

(`<p style="xyz">ExampleName</p>`)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `div` instead of `p` or use `<style>...</style>` at the top of the page if you can and also want to avoid a css file

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :) Do you know if there is a way to use br-tags instead of p- or span-tags, because I have the apprehension that our systems can't interpret p- or span-tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display text without any extra formatting that gets added by `p` tags you can use the `span` tag:

```
<span style="xyz">ExampleName</span>
```

`span` is an inline element by default. If you want to use a block element, use `div`.
[More about inline vs block.](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :) Do you know if there is a way to use br-tags instead of p- or span-tags, because I have the apprehension that our systems can't interpret p- or span-tags.

Comment: `br` tags are not meant to be used for displaying text. Their only purpose is to create a line break (i.e. move the "cursor" to the next line).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `<div>`, or `<span>`. The difference is one has `block` display properties while another has `inline` display properties respectively.

Another alternative approach is to use [reset.css](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) which eliminates `<p>` tag's default margin across all browsers. I still would recommend using `<p>` tag if you are concerned about SEO.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :) Do you know if there is a way to use br-tags instead of p- or span-tags, because I have the apprehension that our systems can't interpret p- or span-tags.

Comment: What do you mean "our systems can't interpret p- or span-tags"? `<br />` tag is valid inside `<div>`. For `<span>` I haven't tested yet. If you just want a whitespace use `&nbsp;`.

Comment: The systems we are working with are pretty old and outdated. Therefore it can't interpret tags like <p> or <span> correctly. It only creates large spaces between the lines. Because of this, we are always using tags like <br>.